# Bayes regression: How to find values regression parameters?

Tags: regression, probability

In linear regression we can find the values of regression parameter $\beta$ using the equation $$\beta = (X^T X)^{-1} X^T y$$. However in Bayes regression what we get is a posterior distribution of $\beta$ from prior distribution of $\beta$. My question: Is there a way to find the actual values of $\beta$ instead of just its distribution.

Comment: Its kind of the whole point of bayes regression to not do that.

Comment: @MatthewDrury, But how can we then do a plot of for example the trace plot of parameter for every iteration if we know the distribution  of  parameter but don't know the value of the parameter?

Comment: You probably refer to the draws from the posterior generated by, e.g., some MCMC scheme? If you want a "point estimator", you could average these to obtain an estimate of the posterior mean.

Comment: @ChristophHanck, I am talking about plots of trace of $\beta$ similar to the one in https://www.r-bloggers.com/bayesian-regression-with-stan-part-1-normal-regression/ where for each iteration there is value of $\beta$ that is plotted in the plot. My question is where does this single value of $\beta$ for each iteration come from if we only have distribution for $\beta$ not a single value?

Comment: Suppose beta is standard normal. You can then draw from that distribution via rnorm(M), where M is the number of draws, and plot the draws.

Comment: @ChristophHanck, Does this mean that for each iteration we keep updating the mean and variance of the normal distribution of beta and for each iteration(update) we  take a random draw from normal distribution of beta  and that is what that plot means?

Comment: No, there would be no update, the draws are all from the same distribution here.

Comment: @ChristophHanck, I understood what you mean if beta has standard distribution then we take $M$ number of draws and plot the values. But if we go back to Bayes regression then isn't  the method here to update the mean and variance of beta for each iteration then take random draw?